# does damaging craft influence tactical battles?

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

If I attack but do not shoot down a UFO, and then it lands and I send in a skyranger, will I be facing less live aliens than if it had landed fully unmolested? Does damaging the UFO have any effect, or must you fully shoot it down?

Comment: I'm 90% sure if it lands on its own, even if its taken damage, it is as if it was not shot at at all, on the battlescape.

Comment: I'm with Raven Dreamer on this one. From the few times I can recall this scenario playing out, I remember that after landing next to the alien craft it did not appear to have sustained any damage. Sadly, this was not something I did recently, so I can't be certain.

Comment: @Aubergine - you, you *don't still play X-Com on a regular basis?* ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, it doesn't.**

As usual, the UFOpaedia has all the relevant information, in this case in the article about [battlescape map generation](http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Battlescape_Map_Generation).

Specifically, down at the bottom of the page is the description of how the game determines when and how to damage an alien craft:

> If the mission is against a **crashed** UFO, all UPSs present in the
>   craft have a 75% chance to explode (assuming the detonation of another
>   UPS doesn't destroy them first). This is performed during a hidden
>   "first turn" (actual game play always begins at turn 2).

Landed UFOs have this check not done thus don't get damaged. Without those explosions all spawned aliens are still alive when the battle starts.